# Replacing a message in a jms queue

Tags: queue, jms, message-queue

I am using activemq to pass requests between different processes. In some cases, I have multiple, duplicate message (which are requests) in the queue. I would like to have only one. Is there a way to send a message in a way that it will replace an older message with similar attributes? If there isn't, is there a way to inspect the queue and check for a  message with specific attributes (in this case I will not send the new message if an older one exists).

Clarrification (based on Dave's answer): I am actually trying to make sure that there aren't any duplicate messages on the queue to reduce the amount of processing that is happening whenever the consumer gets the message. Hence I would like either to replace a message or not even put it on the queue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an ideal use case for the [Idempotent Consumer](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/idempotent-consumer.html) which removes duplicates from a queue or topic.

The following example shows how to do this with [Apache Camel](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/) which is the easiest way to implement any of the [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/enterprise-integration-patterns.html), particularly if you are using [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) which [comes with Camel integrated](http://activemq.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) out of the box

```
from("activemq:queueA").
  idempotentConsumer(memoryMessageIdRepository(200)).
  header("myHeader").
  to("activemq:queueB");
```

The only trick to this is making sure there's an easy way to calculate a unique ID expression on each message - such as pulling out an XPath from the document or using as in the above example some unique message header

Answer (score 1):

You could browse the queue and use selectors to identify the message.  However, unless you have a small amount of messages this won't scale very well. Instead, you message should just be a pointer to a database-record (or set of records).  That way you can update the record and whoever gets the message will then access the latest version of the record.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I am actually trying to make sure that there aren't any duplicate messages on the queue to reduce the amount of processing that is happening whenever the consumer gets the message. Hence I would like either to replace a message or not even put it on the queue.

Udi